# Comparing Cell Background colour in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Depending on the the current colour of the table cell I am trying to change the colour or keep it the same when the mouse leaves the cell.  Here is my script:

```
<script>
    $('.tableCell')
         .mouseenter(function () {

             $(this).find(".hideCheckBox").show();
         })
         .mouseleave(function () {

             $(this).find(".hideCheckBox").hide();
             if ($(this).find(".hideCheckBox").is(":checked")) {
                 $(this).css("backgroundColor", "#10657e");
                 $(this).css("color", "white");
             }
             else {
                 if ($(this).style.backgroundColor === "#157fa0") {

                 } else {
                     $(this).css("backgroundColor", "white");
                     $(this).css("color", "black");
                 }
             }
         });
</script>
```

However my comparison (below) isn't working.  How can I compare in JavaScript to get this working?

```
if ($(this).style.backgroundColor === "#157fa0") {
```

Comment: Why not just use CSS?

Comment: have a look at `console.log($(this).style.backgroundColor)` as a starting point

Comment: I really dont like CSS, perhaps it would be a better though

Comment: Html, css and js go hand in hand on web pages. Although you can write everything in JS and no html, css if you want, using all 3 correctly just makes everything easier and prettier. But yes, open your console and check the values.

Comment: Ill try it with CSS, would be interesting still to know why the above isn't working.  I put in the console.log as requested and the following error occurs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

Comment: Basic html nodes have a style property. But you're using JQuery, so the syntax `$(this).style` doesn't work, hence backgroundColor cannot be read from an object that is undefined. You just have to use the JQuery syntax for css things as written in the docs, aka `$(this).css("backgroundColor") === 'yourColor'`.

Comment: This will be easier using `hasClass`, `addClass` and `removeClass`. And style that class using CSS not JS.

Comment: If you can use css instead, do it. If you must use js, the problem you will face is that sometimes you will set a color, but when you ask for it back, it will be reported in a different format. There is a workaround though, of which I give an example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare the RGB values:

```
if ($(this).style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(21, 127, 160)') {
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The problem you have is that different browsers may report colors in different ways. For instance, you may set a color to `#ff0000`, but when you ask for it, you get back `rgb(255, 0, 0)`.

**Workaround**

The safest way to compare a background color is to create a temporary element with the color you want to compare to. Then, you retrieve the color of temp element, and compare that color to the color of the element you are actually interested in. We use this workaround when unit testing directives in angular that modify colors on the element.

**Example (with jQuery)**

```
var getExpectedColor = function(color) {
  // This is necessary because the browsers representation of a color may be different than what you set.
  // For instance, you maybe set the color to #ff0000, and when you ask for it, get back rgb(255, 0, 0).
  var temp = $('<div>');
  $('body').append(temp);
  var expected = temp.css('background-color', color).css('background-color');
  temp.remove();
  return expected;
};

if ($(this).css('background-color') === getExpectedColor('#157fa0')) {
  // bingo
}
```